# The code is running fine in anonymous window, but giving Attempt to de reference a null object in live environment

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am running the same code in anonymous window and it is running fine there I am getting the results what I want, but the same thing I am implementing in the live environment then it is giving me an error Attempt to de reference a null object.

Here is the code snippet

```
String orderId = 'some order ID';
List<OrderItem> oItem = new List<OrderItem>();
oItem = [SELECT Id, Quantity, Product2.Name, OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId =: orderId ORDER BY Product2Id];
    List<Decimal> prodqty = new List<Decimal>();
    List<String> pName = new List<String>();
    if(oItem.size()>0){
        for(OrderItem ordt: oItem){
            prodqty.add(ordt.Quantity);
            pName.add(ordt.Product2.Name);
        }
    }
```

I am confused what thing is going wrong.

Comment: If you run in anonymous window it runs in user mode, whereas in general apex classes will be run in system mode. Is it possible that when running in production you are returning more records than when running anonymously, and one of those records is causing the error. Perhaps a orderitem without a product2?

Comment: It's always better to post the exact error message you receive as well as the code/line that the error notes. You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way this exact code can ever have a NullPointerException.

You can reduce the complexity of your code as follows:

```
Id orderId = 'some order id';
// You don't need to initialize a variable twice.
List<OrderItem> oItem = [SELECT Id, Quantity, Product2.Name, OrderId FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId =: orderId ORDER BY Product2Id];
List<Decimal> prodqty = new List<Decimal>();
List<String> pName = new List<String>();
// You don't need to check if a list is empty before you iterate over it
for(OrderItem ordt: oItem){
    prodqty.add(ordt.Quantity);
    pName.add(ordt.Product2.Name);
}
```

Whatever you think is going on, it's something else. Nothing in here will produce a NullPointerException.